# Is it possible to make an archived google classroom inaccessible to former students?

Tags: google-classroom

Is it possible to make an archived google classroom inaccessible to former students? A teacher at my school believes that this is possible and former student's should not have access to her class. I told her that the she either had to unarchive the class and remove all the students or delete the class altogether. Am I incorrect believing there is not another option. Thank you!